# Change anchor text/icon during audio play using <audio> tags and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am using the HTML `<audio>` tags to add short MP3 clips (~6-8kb) on my page. I am adding the tags using a server-side PHP like so:

```
$soundnode->appendXML('<span class="sound"><audio id="yourAudio" preload="none"><source src="' . $soundlink . '" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio><a href="javascript:;" id="audioControl" onclick="playclip();" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Hear it spoken"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-volume-up pronounce"></i></a></span>');
$node->appendChild($soundnode);
```

On the page, a tag looks like:

```
<span class="sound">
   <audio id="yourAudio" preload="none">
      <source src="bootstrap/pronunciations/jjugar01sp.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   </audio>
   <a href="javascript:;" id="audioControl" onclick="playclip();" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Hear it spoken">
      <i class="fa fa-2x fa-volume-up pronounce"></i>
   </a>
</span>
```

In order to play the said audio file, I am using JavaScript in the form of a `playclip()` method which is called by the `onclick` event of the `<a>` tag. This function looks like this:

```
function playclip(){
    var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio');
    yourAudio.play();
    return false;
}
```

This works great but is there any way to change the **Font Awesome** speaker icon to some other Font Awesome icon while the audio is playing? I know it's easy to do it by adding the code to change the tag in the `playclip()` function. However, I don't know how to ensure the change only applies while the clip is playing and then reverts to the original once the play is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't be too hard.

use the onplay and onpause events:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onplay.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpause.asp

```
<audio id="yourAudio" preload="none" onplay="boo()" onpause="bong()">
```

and inside these functions, change the fa icon.

p.s i know that it seems like its for video, but i think i also works for audio.
hope i'm not wrong